How to bundle lp+buy first your own contract?
How to bundle lp+buy first your own contract ? as here https://etherscan.io/address/0x68ff0e5f034561d0571afe8b586af166f0c254a1

Look at how to do each individually, and then write a contract that does all the calls atomically. This old rescue contract swaps, adds and removes all within the constructor. It was used to pull tokens accidently sent directly to v2 routers but the steps can be can be repurposed to just add lp and swap.  https://github.com/0xMaka/vybes/blob/main/rescue.vy
